# What is the proper way to attach a virtual bridge to an already existing KVM guest?

Tags: networking

I have this bridge virbr0 tuned with eth0 in my host, and an already running KVM Guest with multiple nics installed on it.

The goal is to make the KVM guest reachable from outside the host, this is why I want to attach it to the network bridge of the host.

I've cloned this guest to run some network tests, but I would like to find the proper/cleanest way to attach this guest to my virbr0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every network interface of every KVM guest is presented by the tun/tap interface in the host system. To attach the KVM guest to the bridge use this command: `ip link set master virbr0 dev <tun-iface-name>` for the corresponded tunnel interface.